# A value of type 'Image' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Image?'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

This so ridiculous, why I wouldn't be able to assign a non null-able value to a null-able variable?

is it a null safety problem or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Add `!` at the end of it. Or give me the code and I change it.

Comment: @stacktrace2234 I was using different packages for Image. it's not a null safety problem. Thank you

Comment: @stacktrace2234 That's backwards. `T` is always assignable to `T?` assuming that both `T`s are actually the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a null-safety problem,
left side type is an Image? from library : 'dart:ui'
and right side type is an Image from package:'package:flutter/widgets.dart'